# How can i know that my firebase cloud function is working or not?

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am created a firebase function which shown in below, but i don't how to debug it i am serving this with `npm run serve`

I am trying to creating, updating, deleting data in my real time database, if you see the reference is giving is development. but when i checking my rt DB it doesn't change anything.
first i am editing my textEdit field after i see it doesn't update anything.

```
export const tri= functions.database.ref('/development').onWrite((change, context) => {
      //
      functions.logger.log("dddd", change, context)
      console.log("logggg", change.after.val())

      return change.after.ref.update({ textEdit: new Date() })
})                                                                                 

console.log("1")
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `firebase emulators:start` as covered in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator)?

Comment: @Harprit singh I have provided an answer below.please check

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `npm run serve` use `firebase serve` to test and debug functions locally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `firebase emulators:start`, `emulators:start`  will start the emulator for your functions which allows you to test and debug your Functions locally,You can test your functions in this way before putting them into the production environment. You can interact with the functions in the same way you would when they were deployed once the emulators are running, which can help you quickly find and fix bugs and errors.you can check this [document1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator) which is shared in above comment and also this [document2](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure) for more information

To initialize Firebase Emulators locally

> - Install the Firebase CLI. If you don't already have the Firebase CLI installed, [install it now](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install_the_firebase_cli).
> - Initialize the current working directory as a Firebase project.
>
>   ```
>   firebase init
>   ```
> - Initialize Firebase emulators on  local development machine.
>
>   ```
>   firebase init emulators
>   ```
> - To run the Cloud Functions emulator, use the emulators:start command:
>
>   ```
>   firebase emulators:start
>   ```
> - The `emulators:start` command will start emulators for Cloud Functions, Cloud Firestore, Realtime Database, and Firebase Hosting
>   based on the products you have initialized in your local project using
>   firebase init. If you want to start a particular emulator, use the
>   --only flag:
>
>   ```
>   firebase emulators:start --only functions
>   ```

Comment: `firebase init emulators` to initiate emulator in locally it add some thing like this ` "singleProjectMode": true,
    "database": {
      "port": 9000
    }  ` firebase.json file then use ` firebase emulators:start`

or follow this link
https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure

Comment: @Harpritsingh Please have a look at my updated answer.